# Declaring an HTMLElement Typescript

Tags: typescript

In the default TypeScript HTML app from visual studio, I added

```
HTMLElement
```

to the first line of the window.onload event handler, thinking that I could provide a type for "el".

thus:

```
class Greeter {
    element: HTMLElement;
    span: HTMLElement;
    timerToken: number;

    constructor (element: HTMLElement) { 
        this.element = element;
        this.element.innerText += "The time is: ";
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.element.appendChild(this.span);
        this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
    }

    start() {
        this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
    }

}

window.onload = () => {
    HTMLElement el = document.getElementById('content');
    var greeter = new Greeter(el);
    greeter.start();
};
```

I get an error

> Compile Error.  See error list for details  .../app.ts (25,17):
>   Expected ';'

Any clue why?  I suspect I am missing something obvious.

Comment: `let el: HTMLElement` or `let el: Node`

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The type comes *after* the name in TypeScript, partly because types are optional.

So your line:

```
HTMLElement el = document.getElementById('content');
```

Needs to change to:

```
const el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content');
```

Back in 2013, the type `HTMLElement` would have been inferred from the return value of `getElementById`, this is still the case *if you aren't using strict null checks* (but you *ought* to be using the strict modes in TypeScript). If you are enforcing strict null checks you will find the return type of `getElementById` has changed from `HTMLElement` to `HTMLElement | null`. The change makes the type more correct, because you don't always find an element.

So when using type mode, you will be encouraged by the compiler to use a type assertion to ensure you found an element. Like this:

```
const el: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('content');

if (el) {
  const definitelyAnElement: HTMLElement = el;
}
```

I have included the types to demonstrate what happens when you run the code. The interesting bit is that `el` has the narrower type `HTMLElement` within the `if` statement, due to you eliminating the possibility of it being null.

You can do exactly the same thing, with the same resulting types, without any type annotations. They will be inferred by the compiler, thus saving all that extra typing:

```
const el = document.getElementById('content');

if (el) {
  const definitelyAnElement = el;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I do like adding the type even if it can be inferred though!  I am glad both are supported.

Comment: In my experience it returns HTMLElement | null which is not comparable to HTMLElement in typescript.  So unless processing stops here this is not the whole story

Comment: Hi @Clarence - yes, this changed since 2013, so I'll some additional information around that.

Comment: The declaration of the element must be: `const el = document.getElementById('content') as HTMLElement;`

Comment: @Orici - I disagree. The type returned from `getElementById` is `HTMLElement` or with strict null checks `HTMLElement | null`. In either case, allowing the `el` variable to have an inferred type is the path to success, as per the last example in the answer.

Answer (score 17):

Okay: weird syntax!

```
var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content');
```

fixes the problem.  I wonder why the example didn't do this in the first place?

complete code:

```
class Greeter {
    element: HTMLElement;
    span: HTMLElement;
    timerToken: number;

    constructor (element: HTMLElement) { 
        this.element = element;
        this.element.innerText += "The time is: ";
        this.span = document.createElement('span');
        this.element.appendChild(this.span);
        this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString();
    }

    start() {
        this.timerToken = setInterval(() => this.span.innerText = new Date().toUTCString(), 500);
    }

    stop() {
        clearTimeout(this.timerToken);
    }

}

window.onload = () => {
    var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content');
    var greeter = new Greeter(el);
    greeter.start();
};
```

Comment: I was using Visual Studio 2010 or 2013 at the time, I think.  It has been a while :)

Comment: Is there really a HTMLElement type in TypeScript?!

Comment: There is an HTMLElement _interface_ in TypeScript.  It has no runtime effect.

Answer (score 7):

In JavaScript you declare variables or functions by using the keywords var, let or function. In TypeScript classes you declare class members or methods without these keywords followed by a colon and the type or interface of that class member.

It’s just syntax sugar, there is no difference between:

```
var el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('content');
```

and:

```
var el = document.getElementById('content');
```

On the other hand, because you specify the type you get all the information of your HTMLElement object.

Answer (score 4):

try use typing for elementHTML like this:

```js
window.onload = () => {
    const el= <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('content');
    constgreeter = new Greeter(el);
    greeter.start();
};
```

Comment: Without null checking, this is prone to getting a type error in the event of no #content element existing in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Note that const declarations are block-scoped.

```
const el: HTMLElement | null = document.getElementById('content');

if (el) {
  const definitelyAnElement: HTMLElement = el;
}
```

So the value of definitelyAnElement is not accessible outside of the {}.

(I would have commented above, but I do not have enough Reputation apparently.)