# How to type a DOM element in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Is it possible to type a DOM element in TypeScript? If it is how do we do?
For example, can we do:

```
var myDocument: any = document;
```

Comment: Take a look at the answers to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14742194/398606). You can use `HTMLElement` or the type can be inferred in some cases.

Answer (score 2):

tl;dr; Just use `document` in your code.

The types of all DOM nodes are already defined in the TypeScript compiler. See [the documentation on the compiler option `--lib`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) about the value `DOM`.

Notice: You shouldn't do `let myDocument: any = document`. The `: any` would lose the typing. You can do: `let myDocument = document` and the type of `myDocument` will be inferred from the type of `document`.