# How to give access to HTML element based on user name?

Tags: html, angular, angular-elements

I have a button that I need to give permission to a specific user If he logs in into a website. I can do this with *ngIf on the HTML file but I would like to give the HTML element an id and then do the permission operation on the .ts file.

```html
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right" *ngIf="user.name === 'John'" >
  <li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="Private">Private</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
 <ul class="navbar-nav float-right" id="ulPrivate">
      <li class="nav-item" >
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="Private">Private</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

**TS**

```
const el: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('ulPrivate');
el.setAttribute("style", "color:red; border: 1px solid blue;");
```

Obviously change the style to "display:none" or "display:block" depending on the appropriate privacy condition: `user.name === 'John'`

**References:**

[Declaring an HTMLElement Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14742194/declaring-an-htmlelement-typescript)

[How to set multiple CSS style properties in typescript for an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655393/how-to-set-multiple-css-style-properties-in-typescript-for-an-element)

Answer (score 0):

You can use template ref syntax in your html file. And use [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) at your component code.

```
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right" #privateUL>
  <li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="Private">Private</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

--

```
  @ViewChild("privateUL", { static: false }) ul: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // modify your element
    this.ul.nativeElement.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
  }
```

Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2z9pbt) sample.

Answer (score 0):

1. if you want add id to the element dynamically you can do it this way

```
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right"  [attr.id]="'test'">
  <li class="nav-item" >
    <a class="nav-link" routerLink="Private">Private</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

1. But I will recommended to you usage of ngIf instead of id like this

```
<ul class="navbar-nav float-right"  *ngIf="FunctionFromTs()">
 <li class="nav-item" >
   <a class="nav-link" routerLink="Private">Private</a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

FunctionFromTs() which will return boolean status of visibility